# MongoDB WiredTiger Storage Engine cacheSizeGB configure option

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

What's the minimum number of cacheSizeGB can I configure which configure option introduce by MongoDB 3.0.0 in WiredTiger Storage Engine?

Represent the number of cacheSizeGB must be integer? Can I configure it with floating number like 15.5?

I cannot find the detail from MongoDB official document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know this is quite old, but as I fall on this question looking for an answer, here it is:

Changed in version **3.4**: Values can range from **256MB to 10TB** and can be a **float**. In addition, the default value has also changed.

default:
50% of RAM minus 1 GB, or
256 MB.
Avoid increasing the WiredTiger internal cache size above its default value.

If you run mongod in a container (e.g. lxc, cgroups, Docker, etc.) that does not have access to all of the RAM available in a system, you must set storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB to a value less than the amount of RAM available in the container. The exact amount depends on the other processes running in the container.

source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB

Comment: "you must set storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB to a value less than the amount of RAM available in the container." If the cgroup applies to the mongod only, should the value exactly match the RAM amount of the cgroup memory limit?

Comment: Hold on, where in the docs does it say "values can range from 256MB to 10TB"?  The minimum _default_ is 256MB.